# Apache authenticate group of matching subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, groups, directory

I have a unique scenario here - one that probably has come up in the past.  I have a directory that is being protected by an LDAP authentication on my Apache server.  In this directory (call it /svn - yes, it's a subversion directory), there are projects as subdirectories.

I want to restrict the users who gain access to this subdirectory based on a group file.  However, I don't want to add a special line in my `httpd.conf` file for every project that gets created.  Instead, the URL of the subdirectory will match the name of the group.

So for example, I may have the project "calendar".  My SVN URL would be "http://myserver.com/svn/caldendar" - and the only users who should have access to this repository would be listed in my `groups.txt` file as:

```
calendar:user1 user2
```

So even if someone can authenticate against LDAP, only `user1` and `user2` should be allowed in.

Is there an easier way to do this?  Perhaps setup a variable for the subdirectory and say `Require ldap-group variable`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I found the solution in the form of SVN Access control.

Using `authz_svn_module`, my Subversion directory in the Apache configuration looks like:

```
<Location /svn>
  # Tell apache this is a subversion repository
  DAV svn
  # Where the subversion repository list exists on the file system
  SVNParentPath "/var/svn"
  # What kind of authentication     
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted!"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPBindDN "YOUR BIND DN"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "YOUR BIND PASSWORD"
  AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://yourldapserver.com:636/other_info"
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/svnaccess.txt
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Pretty basic - the important line here is the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` - this points to the file that will be generated automatically and hold which users have permission to which directories.

This "svnaccess.txt" file would look something like this:

```
[project1:/]
joe_user = rw
mary_beth = rw
$anonymous = r

[project2:/]
james_smith = rw

[project3:/]
john_deere = rw
$anonymous = r
```

The usernames listed here are the usernames authenticated by LDAP.  They do not need to be registered by Subversion (they're carried with the user upon authentication).  The `@anonymous` is a wild-card: anyone that is not authenticated, or that may satisfy another `Allow` directive in your Apache configuration.  This file should only be readable by root (or whoever starts the Apache service).

The creation of this file can be automatically generated - depending on where your information is coming from.  In my case, I have a Redmine server that holds information about users and projects, and which user has access to which project.  A short Python script can be written to extract that information from the database and used to generate this file automatically (if used as a cron job).  It's a round-about way of doing things, but after you get it working and automated, you don't have to worry about rewriting authentication rules again for each new project/subversion repository created.

(And on the plus side, changes to this "svnaccess.txt" file doesn't require an Apache restart!)